# Repeater only renders first row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made an ASP.NET repeater that should show everything posted in a form, but it only shows the first row.

Website code:

```
<div id="Complaints">
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">                
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="detail">
        <b>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Namn") %>'>'></asp:Label></b>&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Adress") %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Telefonnummer") %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Epost_address") %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <b>Meddelande:</b>&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Kommentar") %>'></asp:Label><br />
       </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

The website.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadComplaints();
}

private void loadComplaints()
{
    using (DatabaseEntities1 db = new DatabaseEntities1())
    {
        var complaints = from all in db.Table
                       select all;
        foreach (var rad in complaints)
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = complaints.ToList();
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function that should put all the complaints in the database

```
public void sendComplaint(string namn, string adress, string telefonnummer,        string mail, string kommentar)
{
    DatabaseEntities1 db = new DatabaseEntities1();
    Table klag = new Table();
    klag.Namn = namn;
    klag.Adress = adress;
    klag.Telefonnummer = telefonnummer;
    klag.Epost_address = mail;
    klag.Kommentar = kommentar;
    db.Table.Add(klag);
    db.Table.Attach(klag);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some people said that I don't need to bind it each time, but even if I don't do that it still shows only the first row.

Comment: Yeah, i've misread question. How many `complaints` do you have in your table? maybe its really just one record? How many items in `DataSource` property after assigning value there?

Comment: Right so I just checked the database and only the first complaint was in it. I included the function in the web service which should add all the complaints and info to the database, not sure what's wrong..

Comment: Your method that's "adding all the complaints" is adding a single complaint.

Comment: How would you suggest I fix it while keeping the web service function intact?